# Change URL Address make short in PHP

Tags: url, address-bar, short-url

I have Url as:

```
localhost/ab/directory.php?id=200
```

id=200 is jenny id member

how to change it to

```
localhost/ab/jenny
```

is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question!

Comment: What webserver you are on? Apache or IIS?

Comment: How come everyone assume that he is on Apache?

Comment: @Nirmal: Because his script is named `directory.php`.

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to use mod_rewrite, a module available in apache. This will be managed by an .htaccess file within your web directory. AddedBytes has a nice tutorial for beginners on url-rewriting.

See: http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in at least 2 different ways:

- Use mod_rewrite for Apache to map the SEO friendly URL to your querystring based URL.
- Make `/ab` a php script that inspects the `PATH_INFO` to retrieve `/jenny`. You'll have to configure Apache to treat scripts with no extension as php scripts for this to work.

Comment: i interest for ponit 2.
'localhost/ab/directory.php?id=200', sorry 'ab' is my project.

sample: i have home.php, in home.php i call localhost/ab/directory.php?id=200 using href. and then i wan to direct to directory.php, but i want to change in address bar be 'localhost/ab/jenny'.
in directory.php, only get jenny and call mysql to get detail name,address, etc.

Can you give sample for point 2, sorry my english bad.thank you

Comment: @Iwan: I'm sorry, in order for option 2 to work, `/ab` would have to be an actual php script, not a directory as it is in your case. I suggest you go with option 1 as it is the more widely practiced and accepted of the 2 approaches.

Comment: ok. i am so interest your option 2.but my site is running. any problem if i do that? can you give sample for my problem..please..
thank you.

Comment: @Iwan: See the link in @Jonathan Sampson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check This: http://www.wmtips.com/apache/how-use-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting.htm